# How to get fields in 'auth' variable in Firebase rules?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write a rule for Firebase database.
I want to know which fields are available in Firebase `auth` object which is referenced in Firebase rules pane.

Thanks

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#auth and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken. Instead of repeating the contents of those pages here, I'm going to vote as too broad. If you're looking for a specific use-case/value, open a new question.

Comment: More docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable)

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen Its what i wanted :)